# JS save state of event in debug

Tags: javascript

I have on page tag witch invoke `onmouseover` function

```
<td onmouseover="artifactAlt(this,event,2)"></td>
```

event it's `MouseEvent()`, but i do not know it's parameters.

When i invoke `artifactAlt(this,event,2)` in console it throw error because some parameters of `MouseEvent()` is wrong.

Is it possible to save `MouseEvent()` state somehow in debug mode when function called naturaly not from console.

Comment: You can put a break point inside the function, then hover the element and it will stop there.

Comment: @webdeb,yes i can but is it possible copy event and save for example to disk. And then load when i invoke function in console.

Comment: It's not clear what do you want.. Copy the `MouseEvent` ? 
JSON.stringify(e) and copy & paste into a file, or what?

Comment: @webdeb,JSON.stringify(evnt) retuns only "{"isTrusted":true}".

Comment: well, you can copy the values, manually copy the values to an object which you need and stringify it..

Comment: @webdeb, it has some array's, manually i think is not very good....

Comment: What exact information would you like to save from the event?

Comment: @MaxZoom, coordinates, path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) the mouseover event has information about cursor position and it can be retrieved as below:

```js
function startTracking(event) {
  display("Mouse position at X: " + event.clientX + " and Y:" + event.clientY);
}

function stopTracking() {
  display("");
}

function display(text) {
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onmousemove="startTracking(event)" onmouseout="stopTracking()">
      <p>Mouseover this text to display the cursor position.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p id="display"></p>
```